# How get two's complement of a register value in ARM?

Tags: assembly, arm, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

Say I have a 32 bit signed int in register v1. I want to get the two's complement of this value to store in another register v2. In normal math that means I need to flip all 32 bits and then add 1.

How do I flip the bits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this, ([MVN move with not](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0068/b/ARM-Instruction-Reference/ARM-general-data-processing-instructions/MOV-and-MVN)):

```
MVN v2, v1
```

This "flips the bits" like you asked. Then you just do the +1:

```
ADD v2, v1, #1
```

Alternatively you can just use the NEG v2, v1 instruction (a short-hand for RSB v2, v1, #0) to do the equivalent operation in a single instruction.

Comment: I think mvn only NOTs the register.

Comment: Question was "How do I flip the bits?". MVN will flip the bits.

Answer (score 0):

The efficient way to get the 2's complement inverse (negation), [as a compiler can show you](https://godbolt.org/z/PbWqonYr9), is to subtract from zero, with Reverse Subtract.  This is also what you'd do in "normal math", `-x = 0-x`

```
rsbs  r1, r0, #0         @ r1 = 0 - r0

negs  r1, r0             @ same instruction, an alias for RSBS from zero
```

In Thumb mode, you'll often want `rsbs` instead of `rsb`, as it's more compact than the version which doesn't set flags.  Only `rsbs` from immediate `#0` has a 16-bit encoding, other immediates require a Thumb2 32-bit encoding.  `neg`/`negs` is a synonym for `rsb` from zero.

---

To do the 2's complement identity manually, the steps are:
**`mvn` ([Move Not](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0068/b/ARM-Instruction-Reference/ARM-general-data-processing-instructions/MOV-and-MVN)) to flip bits** (one's complement inverse), then `add` to increment.

```
mvn  r1, r0             @ r1 = ~r0
add  r1, r1, #1         @ ++r1
```

But in practice you'd never do this, using two instructions when one would do.  What is sometimes useful is getting a `0` or `-1` from arithmetic right shift of this or another value, and use `eor` and `sub` to do either `x ^ (-1) + (-1)` or a no-op with zero.  That gives you an absolute value or conditionally negates another number, using the 2's complement identity.

But on ARM that's less efficient than predication:  You could just `rsbs` and do a predicated `mov` if that result was positive, or even better `tst` and a predicated `rsbs` to absolute value with no extra registers.  That's shorter than the bithack way.  On other ISAs, you might still negate and conditional-move, or use the bithack if that's an equal number of instructions.

```
@@ absolute value of r0
    tst   r0, r0
    it    lt                    @ free in ARM mode, separate 16-bit insn in Thumb
    neglt r0, r0
```

Answer (score -2):

Or a bit slower than MVN:

`MOV v0,-1`

`MUL v2,v1,v0`

Answer (score -2):

It seems that there is no dedicated command to invert a register in ARM. But below there is a simple and fast substitute (was checked with gdb/qemu):

rsb Rx,Rx,-1

This does the following:

output = -1 - input

which is a correct procedure to get logical NOT.

Comment: The question is asking for negation (two's complement), not logical NOT (one's complement).  So I think your -1 should be replaced with 0.

Comment: 1's complement: `mvn reg,reg` (move-not) is idiomatic for bitwise NOT, as shown in the top answer that predates yours by 7 years.  Perhaps you misread it because it confusingly presents it like it might be the answer to the title question, and called it move-negative instead of move-not. For 2's complement: `rsb reg, #0` does `0 - reg`.